# Apply a bookmarklet script to a URL

Tags: javascript, url, bookmarklet

Is it possible to append a javascript snippet to a URL, so that when the URL is loaded the scirpt is excuted at the same time. For exemple:

```
<a href="some/path/to/file.html:javascript:alert('Welcome')">Link text</a>
```

Comment: No[!](http://.) - however if you install grease monkey, you could pass commands to it in the url - for example in the hash part

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no! If you can do that, there will be a big problem on security. Script can copy cookies or user data ...